# Joining streaming data with bounded data using apache beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to understand how works a simple enrichment data process using apache beam.

I've designed a first dummy-diagram but I'm not sure how address this:

[image]

I've saw some examples using CoGroupByKey or using lambda but I'm not sure and I feel a little lost on this.

I'm rigth with the approach? Where could I find some examples to understand better?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If your unbound data and your streaming data have a value in common, I would use [`CoGroupByKey`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey). But this does not always work due to the streamed data. If so, you will need to use [side inputs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/), and then you can use the `lambda` expression or [`GroupByKey`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey) to merge the data. You can look at this example of [`CoGroupByKey`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/cogroupbykey/#examples). This is an example of [`lambda`](https://github.com/SockworkOrange/blog-posts/blob/main/apache-beam-streaming-pipelines/main.py), and this [documentation](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-pipelines-with-apache-beam-86cd8eb55fd8) is really good explaining the functions that you can use with Apache Beam through Python.

Comment: Thanks for your response.... I'm trying to Enrich the data stremed using a some properties stored into Google datastore and finally, insert into Bigquery de Data enriched and update the datastore... My Entity and the data stremed has in common an ID... I think, the better option for this is using side inputs

Comment: @RecoJhonatan  If this answer helped you, you can upvote or accept the answer. This can help future users who are having the same issue.